# Knockout Circular Reference (Simple Currency Converter)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm new to Knocout.JS so I have no idea how to accomplish my problem.
Let's say I want to write a little currency converter.

```
<div>
    Rate: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Rate" />
</div>
<div>
    USD: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Dollar" />
</div>
<div>
    EUR: <input type="text" data-bind="value: Euro" />
</div>
```

My model is:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    this.Rate = ko.observable(0);
    this.Dollar = ko.observable(0);
    this.Euro = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.Dollar() * this.Rate();
    }, this);
}    
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

So I want to make sure that every textbox's change event updates another.
For example if **Dollar** is updated I want to update **Euro** too.

- Changes in **Rate** will update **Euro**
- Changes in **Dollar** will update **Euro**
- Changes in **Euro** will update **Dollar**

Here is my playground: http://jsfiddle.net/gnL4we9z/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your `Euro` [computed writable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) and update your `Dollar` property in its `write` function:

```
this.Euro = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return this.Dollar() * this.Rate();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        this.Dollar(value / this.Rate());
    },
    owner: this
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k65mdk2q/).